# Como apagar um caracter dentro de uma string?

Tags: c, string

Neste código eu leio duas *strings* e retiro da primeira todas as letras em comum com a segunda *string*. Mas como colocar um caractere nulo no lugar desta letra em comum nas duas *strings*?

Meu código está assim:

```
char str1[15], str2[15];
int i, j, size_str1, size_str2;

printf("Digite uma palavra de ate 10 letras: ");
fgets(str1, 15, stdin);

printf("Digite outra palavra de ate 10 letras: ");
fgets(str2, 15, stdin);

size_str1 = strlen(str1)-1;
size_str2 = strlen(str2)-1;

for(i=0; i<size_str1; i++){
    for(j=0; j<size_str2; j++){

        if(str1[i] == str2[j]){
            str1[i]=' ';
        }
    }
}
puts(str1);
```

Comment: O que é um caracter nulo? Talvez o que você quer é eliminar esse caracter e puxar para a "esquerda" o restante do vetor, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo.......

Comment: Outra abordagem é você criar um terceiro array apenas com os caracteres que não forem encontrados na segunda string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para deletar um valor de um array em C, você deve mover todos os valores seguintes uma posição para trás.

```
for(int contador = i; contador < size_str1; contador++)
    str1[contador] = str1[contador + 1];
```

Não existe um "caracter nulo", caso faça apenas `str1[i] = ' '` estará subsituingo o caracter por um espaço na palavra original, e nâo o removendo. Você deve rearranjar toda a array.

Answer (score 8):

Você não pode inserir um caractere nulo no meio de uma *string*. Isso indicará o final dela mesmo que você tenha outros caracteres relevantes depois do nulo, eles não estarão acessíveis por vias normais. O que você quer é eliminar os caracteres que aparecem na segunda *string*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main(void) {
    char str1[15], str2[15];
    printf("Digite uma palavra de ate 10 letras: ");
    fgets(str1, 15, stdin);
    printf("Digite outra palavra de ate 10 letras: ");
    fgets(str2, 15, stdin);
    int size_str1 = strlen(str1)-1;
    int size_str2 = strlen(str2)-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size_str1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size_str2; j++) {
            if (str1[i] == str2[j]) {
                for (int k = i; k < size_str1; k++) {
                    str1[k] = str1[k + 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    puts(str1);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/UnK1iB). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fpqbavrx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/DeleteChar.c).

Comment: O nosso amigo aqui de baixo ja resolveu o meu problema, de retirar os caracteres da 1ª string e puxar o caracter do lado para a esquerda.

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 tá ok então. Pelo que entendi do seu enunciado e a resposta dele, não parece que resolve o problema, mas se você diz que resolve, certamente a resposta dele está correta :)

Comment: Sim está, achei que meu problema se resolvia usando seu código, mas o código dele, atingiu o que eu preciso

Answer (score 5):

As implementações das outras respostas **não** possuem um erro oculto.

## Só mover os caracteres posteriores não resolve o problema

Siga o exemplo:

> Digite uma palavra de ate 10 letras: abcdefg
>
> Digite outra palavra de ate 10 letras: bc

```
i   str1      str1[i]   resultado
--------------------------------------
0   abcdefg   'a'       não encontrado
1   abcdefg   'b'       encontrado, move caracteres str1 
2   acdefg    'c'       não encontrado, pois agora 'c' está na posição 1
```

Sempre que houver dois caracteres a remover em sequência, o segundo não será removido.

Para resolver isso, após remover um caractere (movendo os posteriores), deve-se ajustar a variável de controle `i`, assim como o tamanho da string `size_str1`, em ambos os casos (subtraindo o caractere removido).

## Não se deve subtrair do tamanho e usar critério `<` ao mesmo tempo

Ao recuperar o tamanho da string subtraindo uma unidade (`strlen(str1)-1`) você deve fazer o laço usando o operador menor ou igual (`<=`) e não igual.

Do jeito que está, o último caractere não está sendo considerado.

No caso do IdeOne e talvez no seu console, há um problema relacionado a entradas que vem com espaços ou quebras de linha ao final.

Contudo, subtrair uma unidade do tamanho não resolve o problema. O ideal seria usar uma função que remove esses caracteres brancos indesejados do final do input.

## A forma correta do laço

Sem a subtração do tamanho, todos os caracteres são verificados. Decrementando o tamanho `size_str1`, economizamos iterações desnecessárias. Decrementando `i`, evitamos pular caracteres.

```
size_str1 = strlen(str1);
size_str2 = strlen(str2);
for(i=0; i<size_str1; i++){
    for(j=0; j<size_str2; j++){
        if(str1[i] == str2[j]){
            for(k=i; k<size_str1; k++) {
                str1[k] = str1[k+1];
            }
            size_str1--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

#### [Demo no IdeOne](http://ideone.com/G0Cnf7)

## Podemos melhorar mais isso

Existem rotinas prontas para mover blocos de memória.

### [`memcpy`](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/memcpy)

A mais simples. Ela simplesmente copia um trecho de memória de um determinado tamanho para outro trecho de memória de destino.

Exemplo do laço usando esta função:

```
size_str1 = strlen(str1);
size_str2 = strlen(str2);
for(i=0; i<size_str1; i++){
    for(j=0; j<size_str2; j++){
        if(str1[i] == str2[j]){
            memcpy(str1, str1, size_str1 - i);
            size_str1--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

#### [Demo no IdeOne](http://ideone.com/9wiebc)

### [memmove](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/memmove)

Esta função faz praticamente a mesma coisa que a anterior, porém era verifica se haverá sobreposição de memória.

Normalmente isso não é necessário. Por exemplo, nas implementações acima movemos os caracteres da posição posterior para a anterior em sequência. Dessa forma, não há risco de perder memória.

Mas experimente fazer o contrário. Se você tentar fazer um laço para mover o caractere anterior para o posterior, então vai ter problemas. Isso ocorre porque quando você move um caractere para "frente", acabou de perder o próximo caractere. Neste caso a função `memcpy` não teria o resultado esperado.

Segundo a documentação, algumas implementações de `memmove` verificam se o ponteiro de destino está numa posição anterior ou posterior na memória em relação ao ponteiro de origem. Dependendo do caso, ela faz o loop ao contrário para evitar o problema mencionado acima. Outras implementações podem fazer a cópia em uma área intermediária da memória.